# Is there a way to speed up AWS Redshift copies?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have a set of copies that `COPY` data from `S3` to `AWS Redshift`.

The copy statement look like:

```
COPY {schema_name}.{table_name}
FROM '{s3_path}'
IAM_ROLE '{redshift_role}'
FORMAT AS PARQUET;
```

I have 50 files in the `s3_path`, so I run 50 copies because each copy statement runs for each file in the path.

I.e:

```
COPY {schema_name}.{table_name}
FROM 's3://bucket/a/parquet_file_part0.parquet'
IAM_ROLE '{redshift_role}'
FORMAT AS PARQUET;

COPY {schema_name}.{table_name}
FROM 's3://bucket/a/parquet_file_part1.parquet'
IAM_ROLE '{redshift_role}'
FORMAT AS PARQUET;
```

Each file weights `30kb`.

The total time used for the 50 copies is around 500 - 600 seconds.
So it's around 10 second per file. Is there some tips to improve copy speed? Other solution could be par_apply the copies to run in parallel

Answer (score 0):

Is the target table for these COPY commands the same?  If so then you should be using a single COPY with a manifest file. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/loading-data-files-using-manifest.html

COPY runs the best when there are multiple S3 files (at least 1 per slice) and the files are of at least 100MB if there are many more files than slices.  This has to do with setting up parallel connections between Redshift and S3 AND with S3 object lookup times.

Comment: I finally run a single statement pointing to the path without the filename and working fine. Without manifest file.

What do you mean with slice?
How do you setup parallel connections between redshift and s3?

Comment: A "slice" is the Redshift concept of an independent execution thread.  On every Redshift cluster queries are run in parallel with the number of parallel parts equalling the number of slices in the cluster.  There is a default number of slices per node based on node type - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/working-with-clusters.html - which can be altered if you use elastic-resizing.  The total number of slices in your cluster (number of nodes X number slices per node) tells you the parallelism of your cluster.

Comment: When you run a COPY command Redshift will attempt to use this parallelism to perform the COPY but if there is only one S3 file to COPY then only one "slice" will perform the work while the others wait.  If you have 16 files containing the same amount of data and 16 slices in your cluster then the COPY can run (nearly) 16 times faster.   S3 is also a cluster of computers and this cluster can handle a vast number of connections so there is no bottle-neck at that end.

Comment: You are correct in that you don't NEED a manifest to gain parallel COPY functionality but using a manifest is a best practice.  If you have a manifest of all the files in S3 that should be COPYed into Redshift and one is missing the COPY command will throw an error (problem detected).  If you just use folder structure in S3 to determine the files to use and a file is missing you will have silent data loss (bad).

Comment: Great @BillWeiner. Thats a great class. Understood the slice concept. Regarding the manifest great to know that its a best practice, here the issue is if you dont know the files that you have in s3 stills a best practice?

In my case i am copying a path that has been fulfilled by an external provider of data so i don't know of there should be 1 or 20 files, so i don't know how the manifest file should look like. OR the goal is to create before the copy statement the manifest checking which files are there?

Comment: The intent is to have confirmation that all files are loaded and loaded only once.   Scanning S3 for files is all that Redshift does so unless you are looking for a specific corner case there is likely no value is this code.  Since the files come from an external partner, I would look for the process they use to provide a record of the files they successfully upload.  If they use a web site then the same code for  uploading can put a record into DynamoDB (for example).  An independent process for ensuring the correct data is loaded.

Comment: nice @BillWeiner will check for that confirmation of files succesfully loaded. There is a file called success so i guess that's it.